# Solve the differential equation: $\frac{dy}{dx}=1 + a\frac{y}{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are the steps to get to $y(x)$?

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1 + a\frac{y}{x}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is $y^\prime+Py=Q$ with $P=-\frac{a}{x},\,Q=1$. The [integration factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations) $R=x^{-a}$, so $y=x^a\int x^{-a}dx$. If $\alpha=1$, the result is $x\ln|x|+Cx$, with $C$ locally constant but potentially dependent on the sign of $x$; otherwise, i's $\frac{x}{1-a}+Cx^a$, with $C$ globally constant.

Answer (score 2):

You can substitute $y=xv$ and $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=x\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}+v$ to get a separable equation:

$$x\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}+v=1+av\implies \frac{\mathrm dv}{1+(a-1)v}=\frac{\mathrm dx}x$$

Then consider the cases where $a=1$ and $a\neq1$. For instance, if $a=1$, then $v=\ln|x|+C$ and $y=x\ln|x|+Cx$.